# Siren library alert view which notifies the available new update of the app automatically closes within a second in my new Xcode 11 project

Tags: ios, swift

The Siren library alert view automatically disappears within a second.
When I played around with plist file of the Siren library, I noticed that this caused due to the deleted Scene Delegate in my project which causes several issues in my current project and so that I deleted it and added window property to `AppDelegate` as in prior to iOS 13.

This is what I use in `AppDelegate`:

```
import Siren

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, GIDSignInDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?    

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        Siren.shared.wail()

        return true
    }
```

Comment: Could you provide the logs that come up when the app closes?

Comment: app does not closes at all...The alert view that shows just disappears within a second..thanks for the reply mann

Comment: https://github.com/ArtSabintsev/Siren

Comment: this is the library i use